# Wave train 200 m/s meaning

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, seismic

I ran a 60 m seismic line. Energization with hammer. 12 (10 hz vertical 5 m spaced) geophones  and 5 shots (15 m spaced). Record length 0.5 s. Thanks to a borehole near a estrata of gravelly silt man-made (0.40 m) and very soft silty clay (to 5 m) and then clay improves its consistency deeper.
My seismic traces seemed to be ok, but at office the principal wave train gives 200 m/s and first arrivals refractions are that weak that can not be easily identified. I think the principal train wave shadows them.

My question: ¿What is the meaning of a 200 m/s train wave in geophysics?

Comment: This question might be better suited to SE Earth Science.

Comment: I understand. Thank you @Fred.  [link](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17544/wave-train-200-m-s-meaning)

Comment: It is a wave of sound that travels at 200m/s but due to being slower than the train causes an "echo" dispersing the detail of refractive return.